# How can I subtract two row's values within DIFFERENT columns using SQL

Tags: oracle, group-by, max, min, connect-by

I need help calculating downtime in between processes. It needs to be grouped by IMPORTID and then IMPORTREQUESTID. IMPORTREQUESTID corresponds to different phases within the IMPORTID request. So, for example in below data set I need my SQL query to find the **highest** or **Latest** ENDDATE amongst IMPORTREQUESTIDs and then subtract STARTDATE (lowest) of next row from it or rather min(STARTDATE) of next cluster of IMPORTREQUESTID. I've already sorted my query to sort IMPORT ID and IMPORTREQUEST ID in descending order. Should I use "CONNECT BY"? What would be the best method to group by and find highest ENDDATE in rows of IMPORTID and IMPORTREQUESTID and then subtract the lowest STARTDATE from it, within next immediate row or cluster of IMPORTREQUESTIDs? Basically, I am trying to calculate the gap time between when a process is finished and when next process starts. See below table for sample data:

```
IMPORTID IMPORTREQUESTID    STARTDATE       ENDDATE
1156     63833              4/23/2017 18:18 4/23/2017 18:18
1156     63833              4/23/2017 18:18 4/23/2017 18:18
1156     63832              4/23/2017 17:56 4/23/2017 17:57
1156     63832              4/23/2017 17:56 4/23/2017 17:57
1156     63832              4/23/2017 17:56 4/23/2017 17:57
```

Expected result: Would be for the above query to return to me the SUM of all differences obtained for entire set of rows and display per IMPORTID in the end:

```
ImportID  TOTAL Downtime        
1156          21 mins
```

OR even better:

a detailed breakdown with the gaps in seconds between each unique IMPORTREQUESTID (Enddate of above row and startdate of below row) as explained and return the following unique rows (max ENDDATE of a phase and the proceeding min(startdate) of next phase):

```
IMPORTID IMPORTREQUESTID  STARTDATE        ENDDATE          DIFF
1156      63833           4/23/2017 18:18  4/23/2017 18:18  21 mins
1156      63832           4/23/2017 17:56  4/23/2017 17:57
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am using Relational Database Mgt. System as in MySQL or Oracle data base.  I am using SQL query on Oracle database. Or rather running SQL on Oracle server to get the information.

Comment: What are the expected results?  I think it would help clarify your question.  So you would want to see the difference between 63833 4/23/2017 18:18 and 63832 4/23/2017 17:57?  Lead/lag may help.

Comment: I re-edited the description or question with expected results. Sorry, I'm new at this, didn't know how to get the table to display properly.

Comment: You just use the {}icon to respresent a code block for better table formats.

Comment: I'm confused wouldn't the difference be about 21 minutes? not 61 seconds?

Comment: You are correct. This is super helpful! :) I got my wires crossed. Very sorry. I ran the Query against Oracle and got the right answer: 21 mins! 
 However, now I need query to be more generic. So, how do I write query to get same results without targeting or defining the IMPORTID?    So, my SQL table is called 'IMPORTREQUESTPARTDONE" which stores the values you have in the SELECT.

Comment: You'll note my answer really begins with after the space and doesn't depend on the importID...  I'm not sure what you mean by more generic.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for thorough breakdown and explanation :)

Comment: Hi xQbert! Just for my own edification, can you clarify what Oracle is doing when we use this statement:

Round((EndDate-LEAD(EndDate)

Specifically, why do we need to do "EndDate-LEAD(EndDate)" ?

Comment: The entire statement is actually `Round((EndDate-LEAD(EndDate) over (order by ImportID, ImportRequestID DESC))*60*24)`  what it's doing is taking the end date of the current record and subtracting the end date of the next record in the result set when those records are ordered by importID and importRequstId. Since subtracting dates results in fraction of days I multiply by 24 hours and 60 minutes to get us to # of minutes.  Since fraction of days was used I have fractions of minutes which I round to the closest minute. The case where we partition, it will not grab the next if importID varies.

Comment: Docs have a simple example which can help clairify https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm and note this is one of many analytical/window functions.  (not available in mySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?  I don't fully understand the question yet..  especially where the 61 sec comes from I get 21 min.  I also don't know why you have repeated data in your example.... So I removed it using distinct.

Two key points here.

1) LEAD is a window function that lets us look ahead to the next record in the order sequence defined.  We could also "PARTITION" so that each series doesn't look ahead unless the ImportId and ImportRequestID match  so

`Round((EndDate-LEAD(EndDate) over (order by ImportID, ImportRequestID DESC))*60*24)`
would become

`Round((EndDate-LEAD(EndDate) over (PARTITION BY IMPORTID order by ImportRequestID DESC))*60*24)`

2)  I used distinct to eliminate what appear to be duplicate records; but I doubt your dataset really has duplicates so it may not be needed; or perhaps you have a join incomplete which is causing duplicates.

```
 With CTE (IMPORTID, ImportRequestID, StartDate, EndDate) as (
SELECT 1156,     63833, to_date('4/23/2017 18:18','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), to_date('4/23/2017 18:18','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1156,     63833, to_date('4/23/2017 18:18','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), to_date('4/23/2017 18:18','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1156,     63832, to_date('4/23/2017 17:56','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), to_date('4/23/2017 17:57','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1156,     63832, to_date('4/23/2017 17:56','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), to_date('4/23/2017 17:57','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1156,     63832, to_date('4/23/2017 17:56','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), to_date('4/23/2017 17:57','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL)

SELECT ImportID
     , ImportRequestID
     , to_char(StartDate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') StartDate
     , to_char(EndDate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') EndDate
     , Round((EndDate-LEAD(EndDate) over (order by ImportID, ImportRequestID DESC))*60*24) as Minutediff 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ImportID
     , ImportRequestID
     , StartDate
     , EndDate
     From CTE) B
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could order the data by the importid and importrequestid in a way that ensures they are in the correct chronological order. Then as noted by xQbert, use lead() or lag() to make columns for your ending datetime and beginning datetime of next process.

```
lag(enddate, 1) over (order by importrequestid) as priorend
```

Then use something like the following function to find differnce.

```
create or replace function timestamp_diff_in_seconds (ts1 in timestamp, ts2 in timestamp)
       return number is total_secs number;
       diff interval day(9) to second(6);
   begin
   diff := ts2 - ts1;
   total_secs := abs(extract(second from diff) + extract(minute from diff)*60 + extract(hour from diff)*60*60 + extract(day from diff)*24*60*60);

   return total_secs;
end timestamp_diff_in_seconds;
```

Then call the function example...

```
select timestamp_diff_in_seconds(priorend, startdate) as downtime.
```